# No indexer option in Eclipse c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-10, indexer

I have installed Eclipse c++ helion on my windows 10 machine. Apart from this i have installed Egit plugin to import my git-tracked project. I can see that under window->preferences->c/c++->indexer the indexer is enabled. However, when I right click y project there is no index option. Does anybody know how to fix this? I've stucked here.

Comment: Is your project set to have a project-specific indexer (`Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Indexer`)?

Comment: In  (Project->Properties->) I have no C/C++ at all. I have it under (Window->Preferences->).

Comment: Hmmm you should have both but I don't have Windows so I can't check, sorry.

Comment: I have installed C/C++ plugin (even though it was eclipse for c/c++ it was not installed), but still no indexer option when right-click the project.....